# Syntax error near ".. AS @variable" when assigning result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why do I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'" from the following code?

```
DECLARE @FirstHole INTEGER

SELECT MIN(HoleId) FROM dbo.Holes WHERE CourseId = (
SELECT MAX(dbo.Holes.CourseId) FROM dbo.Registration 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Competitions ON dbo.Registration.CompetitionId = dbo.Competitions.CompetitionId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Holes ON dbo.Competitions.CourseId = dbo.Holes.CourseId WHERE RegistrationId = 102
) AND dbo.Holes.MarkerId = 2 AS @FirstHole
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you assign to a variable in TSQL.

I presume your intention is to do this

```
DECLARE @FirstHole INTEGER

SELECT  @FirstHole = MIN(HoleId) /* <-- Assignment here*/
FROM   dbo.Holes
WHERE  CourseId = (SELECT MAX(dbo.Holes.CourseId)
                   FROM   dbo.Registration
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.Competitions
                            ON dbo.Registration.CompetitionId = dbo.Competitions.CompetitionId
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.Holes
                            ON dbo.Competitions.CourseId = dbo.Holes.CourseId
                   WHERE  RegistrationId = 102)
       AND dbo.Holes.MarkerId = 2
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, you wouldn't believe how long I was messing with that little bit of code wondering why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @gallie - Just out of curiosity what rationale did you use for accepting an answer?

Comment: My code now works the way I want it to work.  Is that not the only rationale? :)

Comment: @gallie - I meant why choose the one with identical code but posted later?

Comment: @gallie you should accept this answer as it was posted first.  I did not see it when I was finishing my answer

Comment: MY apologies, I had selected your code and didn't realise by selecting another correct answer it would deselect yours.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks! `@gallie` - Ah yes. On MSDN forums you can tick multiple answers for example but on stack exchange just one. It is of course entirely your choice what answer to choose but if they are equal first posted seems the generally expected tiebreaker.